# Add absolute url in spring json response

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I am building a RESTful web service with spring framework. The JSON response I am sending contains image URLs. Image URLs are stored as relative paths in the DB but to avoid having tightly coupled clients, I want the response to include absolute URLs instead.

For example:
Instead of returning a json like

```
{"username": "user123", "profile_picture": "/user123_profile.jpg"}
```

I want to return a json like

```
{"username": "user123", "profile_picture": "http://example.com/user123_profile.jpg"}
```

Of course, image fields can be anywhere in the response and may be in nested objects.

What is the best place to intercept any returned response and convert image fields to absolute URLs?

I thought of creating a special annotation like `@ImageURL` for image fields, then defining a `@ControllerAdvice` and in method `beforeBodyWrite()`, I go over all fields and whenever I find a field annotated `@ImageURL`, I add the absolute path to it. 
*This works and makes it easy to define new image fields, but it is a lot of reflection with every request/response which I don't think is good*.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem seems exaclty among the ones tackled by Spring REST HATEOAS https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/

Following is just as an example to illustrate of the workings of the API (take this as a sort of illustrative example, please look at the official documentation for the exact details on Spring HATEOAS API):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
HttpEntity<MyUserResource> getUser( @PathVariable("id") long id )
{
     MyUserResource resource = new MyUserResource( ... retrieve from db user data ... );
    .
    .
    .
    resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(MyServiceController.class).getProfilePicture( ...profile picture relative URL... )).withRel("profile_picture"));    
    .
    .
    .
    return new ResponseEntity<MyUserResource>(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In the above code I make the following assumpion: the controller is named `MyServiceController` and besides the GET method shown above to retrieve user data, it has a second `getProfilePicture` method that responds to URLs like `GET "/user/{id}/profile_picture/{profile picture relative url}"`, returning the actual image file contents.

The methods provided by Spring REST HATEOAS (like linkTo, methodOn, etc...) will take care of generating absolute URL mapping to subsequent REST calls to the service.

So, when calling http://example.com/myservice/user/123, this will return to the client a JSON object similar to the following:

```
{
  "username":"user123",
  "links": [
      {
    "rel": "profile_picture",
    "href":"http://example.com/myservice/user/123/profile_picture/user123_profile.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

From here, the client will know to invoke on your REST service the _link marked as profile_picture to get the absolute URL for the image contents.